libguestfs failed with "supermin: error: block size: No space left on device"
When I try to set the root password of a ubuntu cloud image via virt-customize, it always failed with "No space left on device" error.
$ export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1 LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
$ virt-customize -a noble-server-cloudimg-riscv64.img --root-password password:123456
...
supermin: ext2: copying kernel modules
supermin: /lib/modules/6.9.3/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko: needed 1874 blocks (4096 each) for 7675633 bytes, available only 1406
supermin: error: block size: No space left on device: /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d.lgx3ubs4/root
libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1, see debug messages above

But actually, my local partition is big enough. And resize the image doesn't help.

The reason is that libguestfs runs supermin with a default size (4GB) of ext2 filesystem to create an internal image (a.k.a appliance). The error message "No space left on device" is for this appliance image but not for my host partition (/var/tmp/).
Libguestfs runs an appliance (a small Linux distribution built locally by supermin command) inside a qemu/KVM subprocess. But this size 4GB is not big enough to build the appliance on my host (need to copy many kernel modules).
libguestfs: run supermin
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/supermin
libguestfs: command: run: \ --build
libguestfs: command: run: \ --verbose
libguestfs: command: run: \ --if-newer
libguestfs: command: run: \ --lock /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/lock
libguestfs: command: run: \ --copy-kernel
libguestfs: command: run: \ -f ext2
libguestfs: command: run: \ --host-cpu x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d
libguestfs: command: run: \ -o /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d

I resolved this by building a local supermin from source and with below change. The default ext2 partition size is adjusted to 8GB.
supermin$ git diff
diff --git a/src/format_ext2.ml b/src/format_ext2.ml
index 484b4699e8b3..436f008428c3 100644
--- a/src/format_ext2.ml
+++ b/src/format_ext2.ml
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ open Package_handler
  * the size of the disk).  For a 4GB disk the overhead is
  * approximately 66MB.
  *)
-let default_appliance_size = 4L *^ 1024L *^ 1024L *^ 1024L
+let default_appliance_size = 8L *^ 1024L *^ 1024L *^ 1024L

Then replace /usr/bin/supermin with this custom version. Finally virt-customize works as expected.
